# entitymanager.merge() not behaving as I would expect (Creating a new record rather than updating)

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, merge, eclipselink

I couldn't find anything relevant searching. I am doing bulk inserts and/ or updates depending on whether a previous record exists based on data read in from exported CSVs.

What is below persists two records two the database, whereas I would like it to insert and then update that same record.

If there is already an record in the db, it works as expected, just updating the existing row.

Previously, I was checking if null and just doing if/ else for inserting/ updating and everything worked fine. That had a lot of redundancy in the setters, so I changed it to this. My hope is that it will always run the update, but in the event a record isn't found, it will create a minimally viable pathology record that is subsequently updated. The update works fine - the problem is when no prior record exists, it creates an additional record.

Is this because of where and how the transaction is being merged and committed? I do not understand why the second merge creates a new insert when I am passing it an object to update that must already exist.

I can get everything working as I would like, but I want to better understand why this isn't behaving as I would expect. Am I missing a core concept on merge and transactions?

Here is my code.

```
        Pathology pathology = getPathology(entityManager, slideId, mdCallString, CALLTYPE);

        if(null==pathology) {
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
                pathology = new Pathology();
                pathology.setSlideId(slideId);
                pathology.setCallType(CALLTYPE);
                pathology.setCallBy(mdCallString);
            entityManager.merge(pathology);
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        }

        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            pathology.setSample(sample);
            pathology.setSlides(slides);
            pathology.setLocation(location);
            pathology.setCallDx(sampleLevelDx);
            pathology.setPatientDx(patientLevelDx);
            pathology.setRadiologyReports(radiologyReports);
            pathology.setModality(MODALITY);
            pathology.setUpdatedOn(new Date());
            String dtm = lineContainer.get(lineContainer.size() - 1);
            DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.US);
            Date callDate = sdf.parse(dtm);
            pathology.setCallDate(callDate);
            if(mdCallString==colbyCallString) {
                pathology.setRepresentativeSlideDigitized(currentSlide.get(3));
            }
        entityManager.merge(pathology);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

edit: So, everything works as I would hope if I run

```
        Pathology pathology = getPathology(entityManager, slideId, mdCallString, CALLTYPE);

        if(null==pathology) {
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
                pathology = new Pathology();
                pathology.setSlideId(slideId);
                pathology.setCallType(CALLTYPE);
                pathology.setCallBy(mdCallString);
            entityManager.merge(pathology);
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        }

        pathology = getPathology(entityManager, slideId, mdCallString, CALLTYPE);

        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            pathology.setSample(sample);
            pathology.setSlides(slides);
            pathology.setLocation(location);
            pathology.setCallDx(sampleLevelDx);
            pathology.setPatientDx(patientLevelDx);
            pathology.setRadiologyReports(radiologyReports);
            pathology.setModality(MODALITY);
            pathology.setUpdatedOn(new Date());
            String dtm = lineContainer.get(lineContainer.size() - 1);
            DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.US);
            Date callDate = sdf.parse(dtm);
            pathology.setCallDate(callDate);
            if(mdCallString==colbyCallString) {
                pathology.setRepresentativeSlideDigitized(currentSlide.get(3));
            }
        entityManager.merge(pathology);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

a second time, after the blocks that is checking for null. But I would like to avoid the duplication. And regarding the original question, what is the difference between what is being passed in the pathology variable in the two cases that causes a different outcome? In both cases they refer to the same existing record in the db -- so why does the one lead to an insert, whereas the other executes an update..

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps resolved? After thinking this through, it seems as if when no record previously existed, after the first merge and commit, the pathology variable has no way of knowing that its object was persisted (pgsql is doing the generation of its serial pk column). Thus when it tries to merge the second time, unless you query the entity, following the initial insert, to grab that unique identifier, the entity manager can't tell that the record needs updating. If anyone can explain this better, I welcome and would appreciate your insight.

Comment: Possibly.  How have you told JPA about how your ID is generated?  Showing the entity would help.  Also, since you are calling getPathology(entityManager, slideId, mdCallString, CALLTYPE); twice, if it is a new entity that doesn't have an ID set, it won't have the ID set the second time either.  You might try calling persist instead of merge on the first check as this will assign the ID to the pathology instance you pass in.  If getPathology returns the same instance, merge will then work as you would expect.